# scroll div content then continue body

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a div container, which takes 80% of screen, and 2 fixed sidebars left and right, they take 10% each. My div is very large, so I am using overflow: hidden on it to hide the content. When user scrolls down, it ignores the div and just scroll the body.

Now, if I set div to overflow:scroll, user firstly scrolls the div, but then stops, and does not scroll the body.

Lastly, I noticed, that if I hover mouse mouse over oveflow: scroll div, it scrolls, but if I keep mouse over the fixed sidebars, then the body scrolls.

All that behavior is not what I need. I want my div:hidden scroll from top to bottom firstly, and when it is near the end, only then body to start scrolling.

So, I try and detect, once my div container reaches top, then I do:

$(#myDiv").focus(), but still, if mouse is over sidebars, which are fixed, body is scrolled.

Is there any solution to this, to make this work? Especially with overflow:hidden, seems like scrolling is not possible at all?

codepen.io/OrvaldMaxwell/pen/Yraryb Here is the example. I need div named "scrollMeAutoPLS" scroll first, and then continue with the body

Comment: Do you have a working example to allow us to inspect your code?

Comment: Hmm, good point. My website is very large and complex, but I will go on and make some minimal reproduce scenario

Comment: https://codepen.io/OrvaldMaxwell/pen/Yraryb   Here is the example. I need div named "scrollMeAutoPLS" scroll first, and then continue with the body

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
$('#yourDiv').animate({ scrollTop:$('#yourDiv')[0].scrollHeight },800,function() {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$(document).height() },800);
});
```

`800` is a duration in milliseconds.

Comment: This will scroll it automatically, but I want to scroll it with mouse wheel manually. I've made minimal reproducable example here:  
codepen.io/OrvaldMaxwell/pen/Yraryb; Right now, if you scroll, div name 'scrollMeAutoPLS' will not be scrolled, just the body

Comment: @user2426290 I see. But, as far as I know, that would be the browser's work, not our job. If our mouse pointer is over the `<div>` then the div will scroll, if outside, then the `<body>` will scrolled. Yes, it's according to user's mouse position.

Comment: I see, thank you. Probably I can deal with it only with bruteforce jQuery injections